Drift condition for Monte Carlo Markov Chain
This question regards physics systems, like Ising, XY, Heisenberg, with a partition function defined over fields $\Phi$ and an Hamiltonian $H(\Phi)$:
\begin{equation} 
Z = Σ_{\Phi} e^{-\beta H(\Phi)} 
\end{equation}
Where $\beta = 1/ K_{B} T$
This system obviously has an asymptotic stationary distribution, which is an invariant measure of probability (in mathematical terms). It can be proven that the Metropolis algorithm is geometrical ergodic, which means it converge fast to that function.
This last property is equivalent to say it is V-uniform ergodic, which means there exists a function almost everywhere finite V, which picks values from the set of states $\chi$ so that $V: \chi \rightarrow [1,\infty]$, a subset $C\subseteq\chi$ and positive numbers $\beta, c$ such that it holds the following geometric drift condition:
\begin{equation}
\Delta V(x) \leq - \beta V(x) + b\mathbb{1}_{C} (x) 
\end{equation}
Where
\begin{equation}
\Delta V(x) = PV(x) - V(x) \equiv \int V(y)P(x, dy) - V(x) 
\end{equation}
Is there anyone who demonstrated that for this Metropolis algorithm log(V(x)) is a uniformly continuous function over x?
